# Swift strong reference cycles with arrays

Tags: swift, strong-reference-cycle

If I have a class A which has a variable x which is an array of class B, and class B which always has a variable y parent of class A, how do I set up to avoid strong reference cycles. I get an error if I put

```
class A {
weak var x = [B] 
...}
```

(even if I make it [B]? ) and it seems the wrong way around to put

```
class B {
weak var y = A
...}
```

as class B should always have a 'parent' class A.

I imagine this is a standard set up so wondering the normal pattern. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: `weak x` is not really helpful in your case, `weak y` makes perfect sense to avoid strong-ref-cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `B` will always have a parent, and the parent will ensure that it cannot go away before its children, then you can use `unowned` rather than `weak`. That said, `unowned` is somewhat dangerous because if you are wrong, it will crash.

If you want to be a bit safer (or you can't promise that the children will always be destroyed before their parents), then the correct pattern is a weak reference to the parent.

The key is in the phrase "should always have a 'parent'." If you mean *should*, then use weak. If you mean *must* then use `unowned`.

While it is possible to create "weak arrays," this is not a good use of that. Parents in your example "own" (have a strong reference to and keep alive) their children. Children in this system do not "own" their parents, and so shouldn't have a strong reference.